# What should my Redirect URL be for the DocuSign C# base project?

Tags: docusignapi

I'm attempting to run the project located at https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-csharp-auth-code-grant-core. I've followed all of the prerequisite steps listed in their read me file, have a newly generated Integration Key and Secret Key, and when I build the project in visual studio it runs without errors.

The problem is, whenever I try to sample links it redirects me to a docusign authorization page and when I put in my credentials it just gives me the message "The redirect URI is not registered properly with DocuSign".

I've gone to the admin portion of my developer sandbox and added the URL my project is running on http://localhost:8080. I also added in a second URL for where the example code should bring me http://localhost:8080/dsReturn, but I keep getting the same issue and I'm having trouble finding help online.

Could anyone help me with this? What else do I need to change?

The project runs on the following URL/port:[this is the port the base project runs on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCkz9.png)

Comment: what is the redirectUrl with DocuSign Authorization page, RedirectUrl configured in your IntegratorKey should match the URL on DocuSign Authorization page.

Comment: The page that asks me to authenticate with docusign is 'http://localhost:8080/ds/mustAuthenticate', and I've put that URL down in the redirect URL's. So far it has not worked

Comment: You URL for Demo A/C would look like `https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=code&scope=signature&client_id=6e083b63-d83c-430a-8515-d9fabefdcd8e&state=a39fh23hnf23&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com` where in my URL https://www.google.com is my RedirectURL and it is the same in my IntegratorKey 6e083b63-d83c-430a-8515-d9fabefdcd8e.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your application is running on `http://localhost:8080`, the Redirect URI you register in DocuSign should be `http://localhost:8080/ds/callback`.

Note that the redirect URI is a specific landing page within the project, not the base domain.

Comment: So for example, one of the landing pages has a return Url of `http://localhost:8080/dsReturn`. Does this mean the redirect for that specific page should be `http://localhost:8080/dsReturn/ds/callback`?

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that the URLs are registered for the correct integration key (clientId) you may have a mismatch between the IK you use in your code and the one you used to configure the redirect URI.
2. It take 2-5 minutes for updates you make to be reflected, make sure to wait a few minutes and try again.
3. URL must match exactly, http or https doesn't match
4. Confirm your port #. 8080 is not usually what IIS express is using.

Comment: port 8080 struck me as odd as well, but it seems to be the default port they use for this project. I'll double check which Keys my URLs are tied to, and make sure to give it a few minutes to update before checking. Thank you!

Comment: if you can provide a screenshot and/or the URL that your browser is showing that may help. the URL has the redirectURI encoded. You can decode to see what you actually send DocuSign